# Need identity insert permission, but needs prevent truncate permission, how to configure the permission?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with an identity column. Sometimes, the developers needs to specify the value of the identity column explicitly, so we need to let them have the alter permission (which is needed to use the `set identity_insert on` in SQL scripts).

But, they can do truncate the table with alter permission, which actually we do want to prevent them do. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why? Is this because your developers are working in the production database? If so, fix that problem. Developers should NOT have access to a production database. One can also argue that developers should not have access to the production sql server instance.

Comment: They just did it in the program, not by SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't separate the two - if you do give the `ALTER TABLE` permission to a given user, in order to enable that user to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, you also give him the permission to use `TRUNCATE TABLE` - those two **cannot** be separated / permissioned individually.

But you *can* fairly easily make a table impossible to use with `TRUNCATE TABLE` - even if a user has the permission for that - just define a foreign key to it and no one is able to truncate it anymore ...

Comment: hi  Marc_s, it will become more complicated if we define one foreign key..and actually, there is no other table has mapping relationship.

Comment: @WisonHo: just trying to show a potential solution - otherwise, you'll just have to accept that a user with that permission can also use `TRUNCATE TABLE` and you can't prevent that ....

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of observations:

If every time you insert into a table you're specifying the identity value, I'd argue that you don't have an identity column. When you have an identity column, you're saying that there's no extrinsic meaning to that column's value. I'd recommend that you take action to move your table schema to eliminate the identity property on the table. Luckily, that's easily accomplished by partition switching.

That said, if you really need this ability, you can use signed stored procedures. That is, encapsulate what they need to do in a stored procedure and grant permissions on the procedure like you normally would. But in addition to that, you're going to create a certificate, a user based on the certificate, assign permissions to the user, and finally sign the stored procedure with the certificate. Here's the high-level approach.

```
create certificate SigningCert with subject 'Cert for signing stored procedures';
create user SigningUser from certificate SigningCert;
grant alter on dbo.myTable to SigningUser;
go
create or alter procedured dbo.myProc (
   @id int
   @otherColumn varchar(50)
)
as
begin
   set identity_insert dbo.myTable on;
   insert into dbo.myTable (ID, otherColumn)
      values (@id, @otherColumn);
end
go
grant execute on dbo.myProc to developers;
```

Note - in my environment, if we create certificates in a database, that database has a database master key which is signed by the service master key (so we don't need to try to dig up cert passwords on the fly). Which is why the `create certificate` statement doesn't specify a password. You're free to do that however you'd like - pros and cons to each approach.

Some notes about module signing:

- The signature goes away if the procedure is modified. This is desired as you don't want to sign version 19 of the procedure, have someone inject malicious code into the proc, and have it run with the elevated permissions.
- The permissions granted through module signing are only in force for the scope of the signed module. Which based on your requirements, is also desired. That is, you don't want your developers to have `alter table` permissions all the time, but only when trying to do an identity insert against the table.

Answer (score 0):

..view + instead of insert trigger on the view...

```
create table dbo.ihaveanidentity(id int identity, a varchar(20));
go
create view dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity
as
select cast(id as int) as id, a
from dbo.ihaveanidentity
go

create or alter trigger insteadofinsert_for_viewforthetablewhichhasidentity on dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity
with execute as owner --'dbo'
instead of insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    
    if exists(select * from inserted where id is not null)
    begin
        set identity_insert dbo.ihaveanidentity on;

        insert into dbo.ihaveanidentity(id, a)
        select id, a
        from inserted
        where id is not null;
    
        set identity_insert dbo.ihaveanidentity off;
    end
    
    --no identity insert
    if exists(select * from inserted where id is null)
    begin
        insert into dbo.ihaveanidentity(a)
        select a
        from inserted
        where id is null;
    end
end
go

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(id, a)
values(null, 'one')

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(a)
values('two')

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(id, a)
values(20, 'twenty')

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(a)
values('20+1')

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(id, a)
values(200, '200..'), (250, '250..'), (null, '1..id..null'), (null, '2..id..null')


select *
from dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity
go



create user testuserxyz without login
go
grant select, insert on dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity to testuserxyz 
go
execute as user = 'testuserxyz'
go

insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(a)
values('254....')
insert into dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity(id, a)
values(300, 'this is ..A')

select *
from dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity

revert
go


drop user testuserxyz
go
drop table dbo.ihaveanidentity
go
drop view dbo.viewforthetablewhichhasidentity
go
```